# How to fix JWT invalid token. I keep getting this error "err : {name: "JsonWebTokenError", message: "invalid signature"}

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

This is a code to generate a token' my token is: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M2FlMDdjMDQ3ZmQ5NWEzMTgwNDJhNTMiLCJuYW1lIjoia2V2aW4ga3V0b3lpIiwiZW1haWwiOiJrZXZpbmt1dG95aTk1QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlLCJpYXQiOjE2NzIzNDk2MzIsImV4cCI6MTY3NDk0MTYzMn0.ij6io2sjwms0MoMUHpE9JJfI8ELbZSNHDX4j711XWTI

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const generateToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    },
    `${process.env.JWT_KEY}`,
    {
      expiresIn: "30d",
    }
  );
};

export const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authorization) {
    const token = authorization.slice(7, authorization.length); // Bearer XXXXXX
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, decode) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).send({err });
      } else {
        req.user = decode;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: "No Token" });
  }
};
```

Here is my UserRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import { generateToken } from '../utils.js';

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post(
  '/signin',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        res.send({
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
          token: generateToken(user),
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
  })
);

userRouter.post(
  '/signup',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password),
    });
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.send({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user),
    });
  })
);

export default userRouter;
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. But I can't see where you are using the `isAuth` middleware

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in the code, I think you must check the request,
If you want to send a request to the postman, you don't need to use the **Bearer** at the first of token
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying sir. I had already used slice method to slice out the "Bearer" I still have the problem

Comment: Can you show me  authorization value with console.log() before using slice? @Agger

Comment: this part of your code is correct, if you can not find the problem, send me repository github, I will chech it

Comment: Here is the authorization value, authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2Mzk4NGZhZjNkNGE1NzMwOTE0YTM4NWUiLCJuYW1lIjoiYW1vcmFnaGFsaSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW4wMDFAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJpc0FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE2NzIzNjc2NzcsImV4cCI6MTY3NDk1OTY3N30.tMN6yEMwM9mXe8zUC5QYgakdlDr8qCJsQH1MdvC-ZwA